# for some reason hibernate postgres connection slows down my application startup

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

My application starts in INFO: Server startup in [337,971] milliseconds

I have tried setting hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults to false.
I have tried setting hibernate.dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

I can connect using pgadmin to Postgres server in ms and also can query in short period of time.

The problem is in application.

```
jdbc.prefetchsize=10
jdbc.maximumPoolSize=1
jdbc.minimumIdle=0
jdbc.idleTimeout=30000
```

```xml
<property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.auditable">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix">Z_</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Here is the console log for the problematic part:

```
16:41:07.395 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
16:41:07.396 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
16:41:37.401 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
16:41:37.401 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:41:37.401 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4bfc28ec: (connection has passed idleTimeout)
16:42:07.401 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:42:07.402 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:42:37.403 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:42:37.403 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:43:07.404 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:43:07.404 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:43:37.407 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:43:37.408 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:44:07.408 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
16:44:07.409 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
Jul 16, 2019 4:44:29 PM com.etstur.cs.backend.datasrvds.impl.RuleContainer getMap
INFO: Rule map refilled in 219127ms
16:44:30.078 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@110cb9bc
Hibernate: select autocomple0_.id as id1_13_, autocomple0_.status as status2_13_, autocomple0_.text as text3_13_ from AutoCompleteWhiteList autocomple0_ where autocomple0_.status='ACTIVE'
Hibernate: select hotel_id from black_friday_hotels
Initializing ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 324837 ms
```

Comment: It seems from the logs that the pool is creating a connection and it is destroying after 30 seconds,So it is not adding any value ,a pool should hold off minimum connections after it has been initialized.Please change the maximumPoolSize to acceptable value and also configure  minimumIdle more then 1.Also change the minimumIdleTime if you don't want to evict the connections that are idle frequently.  Apart from connection pool this class it taking 20 sec to intialize com.etstur.cs.backend.datasrvds.impl.RuleContainer

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I did like below: but the time is still the same. It started in 17:41 
and still not ended in 17.47 jdbc.prefetchsize=10
jdbc.maximumPoolSize=10
jdbc.minimumIdle=3
jdbc.idleTimeout=30000